# whitespace nowrap on span

Tags: html, css, whitespace, nowrap

In this case:

```
<td>
       Some Text
       <span class="Icon"></span>
</td>
```

I want to get the line break when necessary on my Text but I don't want my span to get on a new line, I want it to always stick to part of the text. How can I do it?

Thanks,

Comment: can you clarify for the 3 things: you have `Some Text`, and then "my Text", and then "the text" -- what are they exactly?

Comment: well, I am referring to Some Text in the description by using my Text and the text (since we only have "Some Text" in the code?!?!?)

Comment: So you want the span element always to be next the the text ? If you don't want the span to get on a new line, set the display to inline-block... and it will always stick to part of the text , exactly what you asked, unless i don't understand the question

Comment: You should include sufficient code to actually reproduce the issue. In particular, you should show the relevant part of the styling or scripting that makes the `span` element display at all; in the code posted, it is an element with empty content and no style.

Answer (score 26):

How I solved my problem by putting one span into the other:

```
<table style="width:100px">
<tr>
    <td>
        I am Showing you what <span style=" white-space: nowrap;">I meant
        <span> Blah Blah </span></span>
    </td>

</tr>
```

Check [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v86tvqn0/).

Answer (score 3):

Replace all whitespace before the `span` with a single no-break space (if you want some spacing to appear between your text and whatever rendering you have styled for the `span`; if no spacing is desired, omit the `&nbsp;` ).

```
<td>
       Some Text&nbsp;<span class="Icon"></span>
</td>
```